# Scaling an array to midi

Tags: c++, arrays, midi

I am working on a project where I am programming a microcontroller to count the pulses of an encoder and increment/decrement a variable accordingly. This number will change the value of a 16 bit digital to analog converter. Therefor the encoder will need to count from a range of 0 - 65535.

Where I am running into a problem is how to scale another (lower bit, midi value, 0-127) number to follow the value of the encoder above so that both number ranges start at 0 at the same time, and end on their highest value respectively.

so when 16BitNumber = 0, midiValue = 0

or when 16BitNumber  = 1023, midiValue = 1

or when 16BitNumber = 1024, midiValue = 2

and when 16BitNumber= 65535, midiValue = 127

etc.

so each increment of midiValue, requires an increment of 512 of 16BitNumber.

I would love to be able to pass a function one number (the 16BitNumber) and have the midi value scale according. So in theory I can store only one value in non volatile RAM as a preset to be recalled later, and all relative arrays will be updated accordingly. I need to be able to count with the higher resolution number so I can have more "steps" relative to the midi value.

my first inclination would be to make a long list of if statements;

```
if ( 16BitNumber >= 1024 && 16BitNumber <1536) {
     midiValue = 3;
}
```

It seems like it would take a long time to type this all out, which im not too worried about, as i cant just write some code to write some code for me. What I am concerned about the most is trying to do something that is fast. Fast encoder changes means the midiValue might be slow to keep up if my code isnt optimized.

My other idea would be to manipulate the index of an array to select the correct value, but this seems like It would be very slow. I would also need to only accept whole number midiValues, which would require modulo division as far as I understand, which is, one more step.

I would really like some advice on what direction I should head in.

Answer (score 3):

Your question does not exactly state the type of `16BitNumber` and `midiValue` but assuming an `uint16_t` and an `uint8_t` types are used you can simply use a shift operator `>>`.

```
MidiValue= 16BitNumber >> 9;
```

Indeed the `MidiValue` is the value of the 7 most significant bits of the `16BitNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

```
7bitnumber = 16bitnumber >> 9;
```

Comment: @APutz: consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem. You can also vote for it by clicking the up arrow.